# How can i reorder a variable having categorical values in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have done some manipulations as below to arrive at the following dataframe:

```
df

   cluster.kmeans         variable  max      mean median min        sd
1               1       MonthlySMS  191  90.32258   71.0   8  56.83801
2               1   SixMonthlyData 1085 567.09677  573.0 109 275.46994
3               1    SixMonthlySMS  208  94.38710   86.0  29  56.27828
4               1 ThreeMonthlyData 1038 563.03226  573.0  94 275.51340
5               1  ThreeMonthlySMS  199  88.35484   76.0   6  59.15491
6               2       MonthlySMS  155  53.18815   57.0   1  31.64533
7               2   SixMonthlyData  574 280.27352  280.5 -48 139.75252
8               2    SixMonthlySMS  167  57.77526   47.0   1  33.49210
9               2 ThreeMonthlyData  548 280.89547  279.0 -11 137.54755
10              2  ThreeMonthlySMS  149  53.68641   50.5   3  31.40001
11              3       MonthlySMS  215 135.60202  137.0  49  34.09794
12              3   SixMonthlyData 1046 541.76322  557.0   2 258.90622
13              3    SixMonthlySMS  314 152.40302  152.0  27  45.55642
14              3 ThreeMonthlyData 1064 541.50378  558.0  10 255.35560
15              3  ThreeMonthlySMS  240 146.00756  146.0  54  37.06427
16              4       MonthlySMS  136  49.93980   54.5   1  31.47778
17              4   SixMonthlyData 1091 788.09365  805.0 503 145.67031
18              4    SixMonthlySMS  190  57.50167   46.0   1  33.66157
19              4 ThreeMonthlyData 1073 785.19398  799.5 500 142.90054
20              4  ThreeMonthlySMS  141  50.88796   46.0   1  31.07977
```

I would like to order the `variable` column based on these strings:

```
top.vars_kmeans
[1] "ThreeMonthlySMS"  "SixMonthlyData"   "ThreeMonthlyData"
[4] "MonthlySMS"       "SixMonthlySMS"
```

I could do it using sqldf as below:

```
library(sqldf)
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
a <- data.frame(top.vars_kmeans,a)
a <- sqldf('select a1.* ,b1.a from "MS.DATA.STATS.KMEANS" a1 inner join a b1
           on a1.variable=b1."top.vars_kmeans"')
a <- sqldf('select * from a order by "cluster.kmeans",a')
a$a <- NULL
a

    cluster.kmeans         variable  max      mean median min        sd
 1               1  ThreeMonthlySMS  199  88.35484   76.0   6  59.15491
 2               1   SixMonthlyData 1085 567.09677  573.0 109 275.46994
 3               1 ThreeMonthlyData 1038 563.03226  573.0  94 275.51340
 4               1       MonthlySMS  191  90.32258   71.0   8  56.83801
 5               1    SixMonthlySMS  208  94.38710   86.0  29  56.27828
 6               2  ThreeMonthlySMS  149  53.68641   50.5   3  31.40001
 7               2   SixMonthlyData  574 280.27352  280.5 -48 139.75252
 8               2 ThreeMonthlyData  548 280.89547  279.0 -11 137.54755
 9               2       MonthlySMS  155  53.18815   57.0   1  31.64533
 10              2    SixMonthlySMS  167  57.77526   47.0   1  33.49210
 11              3  ThreeMonthlySMS  240 146.00756  146.0  54  37.06427
 12              3   SixMonthlyData 1046 541.76322  557.0   2 258.90622
 13              3 ThreeMonthlyData 1064 541.50378  558.0  10 255.35560
14              3       MonthlySMS  215 135.60202  137.0  49  34.09794
 15              3    SixMonthlySMS  314 152.40302  152.0  27  45.55642
 16              4  ThreeMonthlySMS  141  50.88796   46.0   1  31.07977
 17              4   SixMonthlyData 1091 788.09365  805.0 503 145.67031
 18              4 ThreeMonthlyData 1073 785.19398  799.5 500 142.90054
 19              4       MonthlySMS  136  49.93980   54.5   1  31.47778
 20              4    SixMonthlySMS  190  57.50167   46.0   1  33.66157
```

I am just curious to know if this could be achieved using dplyr......my understanding of this wonderful package will get enhanced....

need help here!

Comment: @Cath It is not a dupe of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `arrange` with `match`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
    arrange(cluster.kmeans, match(variable, top.vars_kmeans))
#   cluster.kmeans         variable  max      mean median min        sd
#1               1  ThreeMonthlySMS  199  88.35484   76.0   6  59.15491
#2               1   SixMonthlyData 1085 567.09677  573.0 109 275.46994
#3               1 ThreeMonthlyData 1038 563.03226  573.0  94 275.51340
#4               1       MonthlySMS  191  90.32258   71.0   8  56.83801
#5               1    SixMonthlySMS  208  94.38710   86.0  29  56.27828
#6               2  ThreeMonthlySMS  149  53.68641   50.5   3  31.40001
#7               2   SixMonthlyData  574 280.27352  280.5 -48 139.75252
#8               2 ThreeMonthlyData  548 280.89547  279.0 -11 137.54755
#9               2       MonthlySMS  155  53.18815   57.0   1  31.64533
#10              2    SixMonthlySMS  167  57.77526   47.0   1  33.49210
#11              3  ThreeMonthlySMS  240 146.00756  146.0  54  37.06427
#12              3   SixMonthlyData 1046 541.76322  557.0   2 258.90622
#13              3 ThreeMonthlyData 1064 541.50378  558.0  10 255.35560
#14              3       MonthlySMS  215 135.60202  137.0  49  34.09794
#15              3    SixMonthlySMS  314 152.40302  152.0  27  45.55642
#16              4  ThreeMonthlySMS  141  50.88796   46.0   1  31.07977
#17              4   SixMonthlyData 1091 788.09365  805.0 503 145.67031
#18              4 ThreeMonthlyData 1073 785.19398  799.5 500 142.90054
#19              4       MonthlySMS  136  49.93980   54.5   1  31.47778
#20              4    SixMonthlySMS  190  57.50167   46.0   1  33.66157
```

Answer (score 1):

you can redefine a `factor` (or `ordered` factor) with the levels in desired order (e.g. as stored in `top.vars_kmeans`):

```
a$variable <- factor(a$variable, levels = top.vars_kmeans)
```

See also the [help](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/factor.html) page online, or via `?factor`.

If you desire to order the whole `data.frame`, go by the answer of akrun.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `group_by` and `slice`:

```
df %>% group_by(cluster.kmeans) %>% slice(match(top.vars_kmeans, variable))

#   cluster.kmeans         variable   max      mean median   min        sd
#            (int)           (fctr) (int)     (dbl)  (dbl) (int)     (dbl)
#1               1  ThreeMonthlySMS   199  88.35484   76.0     6  59.15491
#2               1   SixMonthlyData  1085 567.09677  573.0   109 275.46994
#3               1 ThreeMonthlyData  1038 563.03226  573.0    94 275.51340
#4               1       MonthlySMS   191  90.32258   71.0     8  56.83801
#5               1    SixMonthlySMS   208  94.38710   86.0    29  56.27828
#6               2  ThreeMonthlySMS   149  53.68641   50.5     3  31.40001
#7               2   SixMonthlyData   574 280.27352  280.5   -48 139.75252
#8               2 ThreeMonthlyData   548 280.89547  279.0   -11 137.54755
#9               2       MonthlySMS   155  53.18815   57.0     1  31.64533
#10              2    SixMonthlySMS   167  57.77526   47.0     1  33.49210
#11              3  ThreeMonthlySMS   240 146.00756  146.0    54  37.06427
#12              3   SixMonthlyData  1046 541.76322  557.0     2 258.90622
#13              3 ThreeMonthlyData  1064 541.50378  558.0    10 255.35560
#14              3       MonthlySMS   215 135.60202  137.0    49  34.09794
#15              3    SixMonthlySMS   314 152.40302  152.0    27  45.55642
#16              4  ThreeMonthlySMS   141  50.88796   46.0     1  31.07977
#17              4   SixMonthlyData  1091 788.09365  805.0   503 145.67031
#18              4 ThreeMonthlyData  1073 785.19398  799.5   500 142.90054
#19              4       MonthlySMS   136  49.93980   54.5     1  31.47778
#20              4    SixMonthlySMS   190  57.50167   46.0     1  33.66157
```